# MVC3 Razor ViewData

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have an online form. for example it asks for first name and last name. When they submit I send them to another view. this second view has a few more textboxes (password, email address, username) it also has first name and last name though. If they fill out the first form and fill in firstname/lastname i want the second form to display these values since they have already been filled in.

in the first form I am putting all the filled out information into TempData["entry"]

in the second form i am doing this check.

```
        if (TempData["entry"] != null)
        {
            var _model = (AccountInformationModel)TempData["entry"];

            ViewData["_firstName"] = _model.NameFirst;
            ViewData["_lastName"] = _model.NameLast;
        }

        return View("Register");
```

i guess in my view im a bit confused on how to display this data in a textbox. I have this in my view but it doesnt seem to be working.

```
       <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBox("FirstName", ViewData["FirstName"])
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName)
        </div>
```

clearly the line that says...

```
   @Html.TextBox("FirstName", ViewData["FirstName"])
```

doesnt work..

Comment: Just curious, why not pass an instance of the model containing the first and last name to your second view and then use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)`?

Comment: @adrift...just tried out your suggestion and it works perfectly..i like both ideas here...but yours seems to take advantage of the idea of mvc pretty good...thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're assigning the value to "_firstName"

```
ViewData["_firstName"] = _model.NameFirst;
```

And then trying to display "FirstName"

```
@Html.TextBox("FirstName", ViewData["FirstName"])
```

Try changing it to:

```
@Html.TextBox("FirstName", ViewData["_firstName"])
```

The other way to do this to avoid mistakes like this is to define a new class that will contain all your view data keys. This way your strings are contained in one location, making maintenance and changes easier.

```
public static class ViewDataKeys
{
    public const string FirstName = "_firstName";
}
```

Then when you want to access it, you can use

```
ViewData[ViewDataKeys.FirstName] = _model.NameFirst;
```

Comment: brandon...thanks..stupid mistake..always good to have another set of eyes i guess, i was on the right track though.

Comment: @gevjen, no problem. As a side note, you may want to consider using constants rather than strings to avoid errors like this.

Comment: @brandon...never done that before, nor have i heard it before..ill look it up, but if you have any link literature pass it along please...thanks!

Comment: @gevjen, see answer for alternate solution.

Comment: ah..follow you..much better way to do that..Ill make that change..thanks for teaching me a better way to do this..!

Comment: @gevjen, no problem. Formatting in comments is a little hard to read, so I will just add it to my answer instead.

Comment: By the way, ViewData["_firstName"] throws an error in MVC 4, so instead you can do: ViewData["_firstName"].ToString()